# how to add child div background image and applied to entire parent section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to add child div background image and applied to entire parent section.Means i have section as parent class with child div.

```css
.section-bg{
padding-top:35px;
background: transparent url('../../assets/images/bg-page-img1.png') repeat scroll 0px 0px  ;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
 <section class="bet-section inner-section " style="">
  <div class="section-bg"></div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 image-right-pad">
    <img src="./assets/images/img-content/th-1.jpg">
  
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 content">
  
  <h2><span style="display:block">Our</span> <span style="font-size: 54px; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 60px; color: rgb(96, 31, 76);">Story</span></h2>
<br>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore   </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </section>
```

Comment: Why do you need to do it on the child? Why can't you keep it on the parent?

Comment: even though i don't really understand why would you need to do this via jQuery instead of just adding background image in css or inline css , i gave an answer below. let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".section-bg").parent().css("background-image",
          + $(".section-bg").css("background-image"));

});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why you want this ? you can write with CSS or inline CSS the `background-image` to the `parent`

also , in your CSS you set the `background-attachment:scroll` and then you overwrite it in the next line with `background-attachment:fixed` . that's not correct. choose one :)

my only guess is that you want to change the `background-image` of the `parent` depending on what `background-image` the `child` has. so you could do something like this

see snippet :

let me know if it helps .

```js
var bck = $(".section-bg").css("background-image")

$(".bet-section").css("background-image", bck);
```

```css
.section-bg{
padding-top:35px;
background: transparent url('http://beerhold.it/579/300') no-repeat scroll 0px 0px  ;

}
.bet-section {
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="bet-section inner-section " style="">
  <div class="section-bg"></div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 image-right-pad">
    <img src="./assets/images/img-content/th-1.jpg">
  
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 content">
  
  <h2><span style="display:block">Our</span> <span style="font-size: 54px; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 60px; color: rgb(96, 31, 76);">Story</span></h2>
<br>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore   </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </section>
```

**or** without JQ you could simply do this . this would be the logical way to do it.

```css
.bet-section { 
  background: transparent url('http://beerhold.it/579/300') no-repeat scroll 0px 0px  ;}

.section-bg{
padding-top:35px;
}
```

```html
<section class="bet-section inner-section " style="">
  <div class="section-bg"></div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 image-right-pad">
    <img src="./assets/images/img-content/th-1.jpg">
  
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 content">
  
  <h2><span style="display:block">Our</span> <span style="font-size: 54px; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 60px; color: rgb(96, 31, 76);">Story</span></h2>
<br>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore   </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </section>
```

**or** you could just write inline like this :

`<section class="bet-section inner-section " style="background-image:url('image url')">`